# Has anyone used BLED112 v bluetooth dongle? Exaplin its communication process with windows and ble devices

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to know the way BLED112 smart bluetooth dongle makes communication between Windows, and BLE devices. I mean to say that I am aware it makes virtual COM ports. But the question is that it makes the COM port for each of the BLE devices connected with it. Or does it makes only one COM port.

Also, do i need to write some special code for bluetooth connection in Windows with this dongle. Or any arbitrary code will run with this dongle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The BLED112 is a USB Bluetooth LE dongle that contains a Bluetooth radio with its own Bluetooth stack and provides an interface to interact with the Bluetooth radio via the COM port.

With this concept, you can, for example, connect Bluetooth LE devices with Windows 7 and earlier versions. These Windows versions do not include a Bluetooth stack that supports Bluetooth LE.

Therefore the BLED112 has exactly *one* COM port for control and communication with the Bluetooth LE hardware on the dongle. With the right programming, it is able to connect to multiple Bluetooth LE devices at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, but the purpose is to know that whether we can run any normal python script that connects to bluetooth with BLED112. Or is it something more to do.

Comment: @Shubham for sure you can use python with the BLED112 to connect to other Bluetooth LE devices. See <https://github.com/jrowberg/bglib/tree/master/Python> The interface is a bit more complex than the Hayes AT protocol and you should be familiar with Bluetooth LE profiles and services.

Comment: Surely I am, Thanks once again. If any problem, i'll post it again.

Comment: Sir i am able to connect 5 devices in parallel with BLED112 dongle. But the situation here is now that I don't know how to subscribe to all of them at once, and stream data for atleast an hour. Also, when i run the script, few devices get disconnected after some time, and the connected ones start notifying. Please help